# Return Results To Calling Method

Tags: c#, variables, methods, parameters

Passing parameters to a method is no trouble for me, but returning one to the caller method, I have never done and am not sure how to do such.  For example, I want to return soq from my GetStartOfQuery method.  How can I get that data back into my BuildAQuery method?

```
public static string soq = string.Empty;

public static void BuildAQuery(string databaseName)
{
  dao.Database dd;
  dao.DBEngine db = new dao.DBEngine();
  var qd1 = new dao.QueryDef(); 
  GetStartOfQuery(databaseName);
  dd = db.OpenDatabase(SetPath(databaseName));
  qd1.Name = String.Format("qry_PersonalInformation");
  qd1.SQL = String.Format(startOfQuery + "location", "empID");
  dd.QueryDefs.Append(qd1);
}

public static void GetStartOfQuery(string databaseName)
{
  if (VBS.Left(databaseName, 2) == "AC")
  {
    soq = "Select hiredate, terminationdate, employeename, ";
  }
  else 
  {
    soq = "Select hiredate, employeename, timeoffaccrued, timeoffused, ";
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, since soq is a class member, you can just use it in `BuildAQuery()`. It will contain the start of the query. (You then would need to replace `startOfQuery` by `soq`.) Or were you indeed trying to get rid of the "global" `soq`?

Comment: [this is a very RTFM question but the code and suggests otherwise.](http://memegenerator.net/instance/61763889)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all you need is a string:

```
public static string GetStartOfQuery(string databaseName)
{
  if (VBS.Left(databaseName, 2) == "AC")
  {
    return "Select hiredate, terminationdate, employeename, ";
  }
  else 
  {
    return "Select hiredate, employeename, timeoffaccrued, timeoffused, ";
  }
} 

public static void BuildAQuery(string databaseName)
{
    dao.Database dd;
    dao.DBEngine db = new dao.DBEngine();
    var qd1 = new dao.QueryDef(); 
    soq = GetStartOfQuery(databaseName);
    dd = db.OpenDatabase(SetPath(databaseName));
    qd1.Name = String.Format("qry_PersonalInformation");
    qd1.SQL = String.Format(startOfQuery + "location", "empID");
    dd.QueryDefs.Append(qd1);
}
```

will do the trick

Comment: How would my BuildAQuery function (in your example) know to associate the returned value with soq?

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions with the line `soq = GetStartOfQuery(databaseName);`

Answer (score 0):

You should better use a function like this:

```
public static void BuildAQuery(string databaseName)
{
    dao.Database dd;
    dao.DBEngine db = new dao.DBEngine();
    var qd1 = new dao.QueryDef(); 
    soq = GetStartOfQuery(databaseName);
    dd = db.OpenDatabase(SetPath(databaseName));
    qd1.Name = String.Format("qry_PersonalInformation");
    qd1.SQL = String.Format(startOfQuery + "location", "empID");
    dd.QueryDefs.Append(qd1);
}


public static string GetStartOfQuery(string databaseName)
{
  if (VBS.Left(databaseName, 2) == "AC")
  {
    soq = "Select hiredate, terminationdate, employeename, ";
  }
  else 
  {
    soq = "Select hiredate, employeename, timeoffaccrued, timeoffused, ";
  }
  return soq;   
}
```

because void dont return anything and you want a value to be returned. if you dont want to return it in a `string` function you can pass the var as `out` or `ref` depending of your needs. like:

```
public static void BuildAQuery(string databaseName)
{
    dao.Database dd;
    dao.DBEngine db = new dao.DBEngine();
    var qd1 = new dao.QueryDef(); 
    string soq = string.Empty.
    GetStartOfQuery(databaseName, soq);
    dd = db.OpenDatabase(SetPath(databaseName));
    qd1.Name = String.Format("qry_PersonalInformation");
    qd1.SQL = String.Format(startOfQuery + "location", "empID");
    dd.QueryDefs.Append(qd1);
}


public static void GetStartOfQuery(string databaseName, out string soq)
{
  if (VBS.Left(databaseName, 2) == "AC")
  {
    soq = "Select hiredate, terminationdate, employeename, ";
  }
  else 
  {
    soq = "Select hiredate, employeename, timeoffaccrued, timeoffused, ";
  }  
}
```

Comment: `should better use` <= you should explain *why* it's better ;)

Comment: @PeterSchneider well, I don't think **but** I consider than I could always learn something, so I prefer to ask, just in case :)

Comment: The out parameter in the second function  is ok but overkill for simple types and just one return value. Assigning to the "global" soq in a function and returning that very soq is sometimes convenient (think C's `strcat()'), but didn't seem like good design. Better is to not have side effects if the function doesn't look as if it would.

Comment: I am just giving options, He/She must decide, but your comment is accepted.